# Fill a file with an array of struct type in C

Tags: c, file, printf

I need to feel a file with a list of purchase
I declared a type struct name *purchase* that must contain the information : *item*, *price* and *date of purchase* in *day/month/year* ordered by date of purchase.
But it doesn't work and I don't know why.

This is the code source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct Date {
  int day,month,year;
} Date;

typedef struct purchase{
  char item[20];
  float price;
  Date date_purchase;
} purchase;


void fillFile(char Name_F[30] , purchase T[30] , int N) {

  FILE * P_Fichier;
  P_Fichier=fopen(Name_F,"w");
  int i=1;
  while (i< N )
    {
      fprintf(P_Fichier,T[i].item);
      fprintf(P_Fichier,T[i].price);
      fprintf(P_Fichier,T[i].date_purchase);
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to print `T[0]`?

Comment: Perhaps reading [documentation for `fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) would be illuminating. It's always better when you understand what the functions you're calling actually do, and what they expect as arguments.

Comment: You have not shown the code calling the function so we can't tell what's wrong there.  The loop should probably be a `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` loop.  You need to provide the formats in the calls to `fprintf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use *format specifiers* to use [`fprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf).

Also results of `fopen()` should be checked and files opened should be closed.

```
void fillFile(char Name_F[30] , purchase T[30] , int N) {

  FILE * P_Fichier;
  P_Fichier=fopen(Name_F,"w");
  if (P_Fichier == NULL) return; /* check if file open is successful */
  int i=1;
  while (i< N )
    {
      fprintf(P_Fichier,"%s\n",T[i].item); /* %s for strings */
      fprintf(P_Fichier,"%f\n",T[i].price); /* %f for float */
      fprintf(P_Fichier,"day:%d, month:%d, year:%d\n", /* %d for int */
        T[i].date_purchase.day, T[i].date_purchase.month, T[i].date_purchase.year);
      i++;
    }
  fclose(P_Fichier); /* close file when done */
}
```

Comment: Hi MikeCat, nice answer, and faster than [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64194720/2411320)! Except from the non-homogeneous formatting that came with OP's code, a logical error was carried over too: the last element of purchases won't be written in the file, because `i` starts from 1 and your loop condition is `i < N`.

Comment: @gsamaras The element which won't be written may be the first one.

Comment: Indeed MikeCat, the first element will be skipped when `i` is equal to 1, right! ;) So you can fix your answer, by initializing `i` to 0. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the format specifier in [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), like this:

```
fprintf(P_Fichier, "%s\n", T[i].item);
fprintf(P_Fichier, "%f\n", T[i].price);
fprintf(P_Fichier, "%d/%d/%d\n", T[i].date_purchase.day, T[i].date_purchase.month, T[i].date_purchase.year);
```

These are the typical format specifiers that'd use with `printf()` too, so `%s` for string, `%f` for float and `%d` for int.

I'd suggest you to check if the file is opened before attempting to write into it (file pointer is going to be `NULL` if it didn't open). You also need to close the file when you are done writing your data, like `fclose(P_Fichier);`.

---

Moreover, `i` should start from 0, otherwise you'll skip your first element. However, since you already know how many times you want the loop to be executed, I'd advise you to use a for-loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

---

Putting everything together, you should get:

```
void fillFile(char Name_F[30], purchase T[30], int N) {
  FILE* P_Fichier;
  P_Fichier = fopen(Name_F, "w");
  if (P_Fichier == NULL) {
    # file failed to open
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s file.\n", Name_F);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    fprintf(P_Fichier, "%s\n", T[i].item);
    fprintf(P_Fichier, "%f\n", T[i].price);
    fprintf(P_Fichier, "%d/%d/%d\n", T[i].date_purchase.day, T[i].date_purchase.month, T[i].date_purchase.year); 
  }
  fclose(P_Fichier);
}
```